# jQuery Ajax Requests: Handling JSON Response in Ubiquitous Manner

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a PHP script which sends me back JSON (with proper headers, confirmed by response headers in Chrome Dev Tools). When I do a POST request in jQuery, like this:

```
var request = $.post(formAction, formData);
```

I "need" to handle accessing JSON properties differently for `.done()` and `.fail()` (`details` being a property), thus:

```
request.done(function(response) {
    $('#response').text(response.details);
});

request.fail(function(response) {
    $('#response').text(response.responseJSON.details);
});
```

What is the recommended way of accessing JSON properties in ubiquitous manner, so I can just call a `always()` function ? For instance, when the fail() method fires, and I do `console.log(response.details)` I get errors telling me that *that* property is not found.